# Why does my laptop not wake from sleep

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, dell-latitude, blank-screen

When I put my laptop to sleep it does not wake when I move the mouse or touch the keyboard.
From previous research..... I've enabled the mouse and keyboard to be able to wake the computer but still it does not work.
Also when I put on the computer computer it shows the windows logo (windows 8.1) and the loading sign but suddenly the monitor goes blank and the cylindrical symbol on the surface stops blinking

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried holding the power button to competely shut it off. I've had problems like this in the past ussually because the battery has drained.

Try to make sure you have sufficient battery before putting it to sleep.

Comment: Yes. My battery is quite okay.And is usually full when I put it on. Currently the it does not come on when I put it on at first it just displays a blank screen and the cylindrical shaped icon on the surface stops blinking. I have to press down the power button till it goes off and then put it on again before it boots.